# Congruent chords that subtend incongruent arcs

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

I was fairly weak in synthetic plane geometry, so I've been working with (Givental)Kiselev's book. On the first problem set, I've been stuck for on finding an example of congruent chords that subtend incongruent arcs.

Is this even possible on congruent circles, or am I to show that a congruent chord subtends different arcs on incongruent circles based on circle radial size and curvature?

Comment: With congruent circles you'll get congruent arcs from congruent chords. So you must consider circles with different radii.